# ListView inside LinearLayout no longer reacts to OnclickListener

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I am designing a simple app from tutorials that I have seen, and I am attempting to simply display two text views in each row of a listview, a name and a price. This worked and I could select the row and it would activate an intent. However I then changed my xml code so that the listview would be placed in a linearLayout in order for me to have a header at the top of the screen. Now when I click on any of the rows they are highlighted but nothing else happens. I have already tried to making the textviews set to clickable = false in the xml but still no luck. I am hoping I am just missing something simple in the onCreate method. `public class ViewMenuListing extends ListActivity {

```
public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id"; // Intent extra key
private ListView contactListView; // the ListActivity's ListView
private CursorAdapter contactAdapter; // adapter for ListView
private String tableName;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    contactListView = getListView(); // get the built-in ListView
    contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewContactListener);

    setContentView(R.layout.viewmenu);

    //Get table name of menu clicked. 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    tableName = extras.getString("table");

    // map each contact's name to a TextView in the ListView layout
    String[] from = new String[] { "name", "price" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.itemTextView, R.id.priceTextView };
    //int[] to = new int[] { R.id.itemTextView};

    contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            ViewMenuListing.this, R.layout.menu_list_item, null, from, to);
    setListAdapter(contactAdapter); // set contactView's adapter
 }`
```

The only thing I changed in this code was that I used the setContentView(R.layout.viewmenu) now when I didnt before and the list would just be the content view.

Here is my viewMenu file:

`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>`
```

and my menu_list_item.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <TextView 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:id="@+id/itemTextView"
       android:padding="8dp"
       android:clickable = "false"
       android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
       android:gravity="center_vertical">
    </TextView>

   <TextView 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/priceTextView"
       android:clickable = "false"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So basically when you remove the parent LinearLayout (without modifying anything else) it works? Also why do you use a ListActivity when you are defining a separate ListView

Comment: yes, when I comment out the setContentView it works. And honestly I was following a tutorial. I guess it was a bad one at that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are explicitly setting an `onItemClickListener` for your ListView. This really isn't necessary since you are extending ListActivity and ListActivity has a method you can override called `onListItemClick()`. I would override the `onListItemClick()` method instead of explicitly setting an `onItemClickListener`. [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView, android.view.View, int, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29)

Comment: would I then just place everything I have in my onItemClickListener into the override onListItemClick()? Sorry a beginner here.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Make sure to extend ListActivity and NOT Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct following things

```
 contactListView = getListView(); and setListAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

The above syntax can be only used if your class is extending ListActivity .In your case you are extending Activity,So above Approach will not work.

Your menu_list_item.xml looks perfectly fine to me.
in viewmenu.xml file make following correction while specifying id for listview.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Please see to this corrected code.

```
public class SampleActivity extends ListActivity
{
    public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id"; // Intent extra key
    private ListView contactListView; // the ListActivity's ListView
    private CursorAdapter contactAdapter; // adapter for ListView
    private String tableName;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); // get the
                                                                // built-in
                                                                // ListView
        contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.viewmenu);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        tableName = extras.getString("table");

        // map each contact's name to a TextView in the ListView layout
        String[] from = new String[]
        { "name", "price" };
        int[] to = new int[]
        { R.id.itemTextView, R.id.priceTextView };

        contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(SampleActivity.this,
                R.layout.menu_list_item, null, from, to);
        contactListView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long arg3)
    {

    }
}
```

Now in onListItemClick method you can write whatever logic you want.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond and it is very helpful when people actually write out the code to help show the solution. However Alex Fu's solution worked before I saw this. Thanks again!